Does anyone know of a open source solution for audio question and answer, using pyaudio?
all.
I'm trying to deliver a survey (60 questions in total) using audio. That is, the question is played in audio, and the participant's response is recorded in audio. Ask one question, get one answer. Each question is scored with a maximum of 5 points and a minimum of 1 point. Finally, calculate the total score.
Does anyone know an open source solution for that?

Do you want the software to decode the audio and automatically assign points?

If you just want question answers (without any AI grader), you can write a python code that will play the question audio files one by one, wait for the user to click next, and will record the answers one by one

I wanna make it fully audio-traced, without clicking the button for the next question. Is there any function in Python to keep recording until the participant responds in audio? And, automatically assigning points is preferred.  BTW: Is there an open-source digital human in Python that can match the lips to ask the questions?

There might be some libraries in python to do this, but I don't know, ask Google. These might help https://github.com/topics/python-voice-assistant Otherwise, you will have to write it yourself in python.

open-source digital human in Python - check out https://github.com/asanchezyali/talking-avatar-with-ai
